# Clarification of algebra in moment generating functions

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

Suppose $X$ has a range $\{1,2,\dots n \}$ and $p_X(j)=1/n$ for $1\leq j \leq n$ (uniform distribution). Then \begin{align*} 
g(t)&=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}e^{tj}\\
&=\frac{1}{n}(e^t+e^{2t}+\cdots+e^{nt})\\
&=\frac{e^t(e^{nt}-1)}{n(e^t-1)} \end{align*}

I don't understand how the algebra goes from step 2 to step 3 here. I understand factoring out an $e^t$, but how does the denominator come about. Is this polynomial division?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are applying the formula for a finite geometric series,

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n x^k = \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}.$$

This formula can be derived in various ways, including some which involve polynomial division.

Here is one approach :

Let,

$$ S_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n x^k ,$$

and note that,

$$ x S_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n x^{k+1} ,$$

$$ x S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} x^{k} ,$$

$$ x S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} x^{k} + x^{n+1} ,$$

$$ 1+ x S_n(x) = 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n} x^{k} + x^{n+1} ,$$

$$ 1+ x S_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} x^{k} + x^{n+1} ,$$

$$ 1+ x S_n(x) = S_n(x) + x^{n+1} ,$$

$$  x S_n(x) = S_n(x) + x^{n+1}-1 ,$$

$$  x S_n(x) - S_n(x) = x^{n+1}-1 ,$$

$$  (x-1) S_n(x)  = x^{n+1}-1 ,$$

$$  S_n(x)  = \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1} ,$$

Answer (score 4):

It's a geometric series: $1 + (e^t) + (e^t)^2+...+(e^t)^{n-1}$ with the sum given as a part of your expression.